# Check for .net core in wix

Tags: .net-core, wix

I'm building a wix installer for an application that uses .NET core. How do I ensure that .NET core is installed before allowing the install?  I can't seem to find the right condition to check.

Comment: Which version of .NET Core?

Comment: 3.1 long term support